# Expanding UITextView inside a Stack View with scrolling enabled

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout, uitextview, uistackview

I am trying to achieve something with Auto Layout and Stackview. I have a Vertical Stackview with a UIView, UITextView, and UIView in it as shown below.

[image]

I have checked out the previous answers here but couldn't find a clean solution to achieve this.

The `UITextView` is editable and must expand as the user types in it - for this I have disabled the scroll for the `UITextView` in the IB. I also have a height constraint set on the UITextView set to "Greater than or equal to" 10 and number of lines set to 0, so that the `UITextView` takes the intrinsic height at run time while the user types. I also want the expansion of the UITextView to continue until the `UIStackView` bottom edge reaches the Keypad accessory's top edge. I have been somewhat able to achieve the expanding `UITextView` part with my stack view pinned to the top, trailing, and leading edges of the Superview but I keep getting an error that the `stackview needs Y position or height` which is understandable but if I give it a fixed height or bottom constraint then the UITextView simply won't expand.

I also am not sure how to stop the expansion of the UITextView when it reaches the top edge of the Keyboard accessory view.

The code that I have so far is

```
let allowedHeight = self.view.frame.height - (self.keyboardHeight! + self.accessory.frame.height)
```

Basically find the allowed height in the view frame by subtracting the keyboardheight+Accessory view height. This calculation happens correctly. Next I do this (inside `textViewDidChange`) in hopes that just enabling/disabling the scroll on the `UITextView` would work but it clearly doens't since the whole text view then weirdly jumps up and down with every key stroke.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
   if stackView.frame.height >= allowedHeight{
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        }

   if stackView.frame.height < allowedHeight{
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple notes...

I think you'll be better off setting the Max Height of your `UITextView` rather than of your `UIStackView`. The Text View will expand / contract based on its content, so you can set a `<=` height constraint.

Calculate the "elementsHeight" - the vertical size used by your top and bottom views, plus any spacing - and set the "max text view height" to the view height minus elementsHeight ... and subtract keyboard height when visible.

Update the text view's height constraint constant when "max text view height" changes.

Then set up an Observer for the text view's `.contentSize` ... and enable / disable scrolling based on `.contentSize.height` compared to "max text view height".

Needs a bit of hoop-jumping, to make sure you update sizes when subviews are laid-out, and to make sure you don't get in a recursion loop.

This is how I set it up:

[image]

The initial height constraint on the text view is `<= 40` - but that doesn't really matter, as it will be changed via code every time the views layout differently.

I put up an example on GitHub -- it works, but is really just a starting-point. Take a look if you're interested, and pick it apart. https://github.com/DonMag/ExpandingTextView

Comment: thanks and thanks for the code. I will give this a try.

Comment: this is working flawlessley. One caveat for iphone X. The safe area in iPhone X adds 22 pts to the y offset by default for some reason so adding just the y offset of the stackview was pushing down the whole thing behind the keyboard by 22px. Not the end of the world and easily fixable. Thank you again!