# Unexpected behaviour of autolayout when isScrollEnabled of TextView is set to false

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit

I'm trying to make growing textview and make it scrollable at some content size. What i'm doing is:

```swift
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.contentSize.height > 100 && !textView.isScrollEnabled {
            let frame = textView.frame
            textView.isScrollEnabled = true
            let heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = .init(item: textView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: frame.height)
            heightConstraint.identifier = "height"
            textView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
        }
        
        if textView.contentSize.height < 100 && textView.isScrollEnabled {
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            let heightConstraint = textView.constraints.first { constraint in
                constraint.identifier == "height"
            }
            textView.removeConstraint(heightConstraint!)
        }
        print(textView.contentSize.height, textView.frame.height)
    }
```

if content size is greater than 100 i enable the scroll and add constraint for height

if content size is less than 100 i disable the scroll and remove the constraint (i expect that textview to fit to its content, as it usually does when scroll is disabled)

i have no problems with enabling the scroll, but when contentsize becomes less than 100, the second if statement fires and the textview for some reason takes the whole screen space. when i call textViewDidChange again (by deleting or adding smth to textview) **both ifs** fire and everything works as it should be.

what i tried to do is to call `textview.sizeToFit()` and `view.layoutIfNeeded()` but had no success. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing a lot more than you need to do.

A better approach would be to create the Height constraint, equal to a constant value of 100, and then activate/de-activate it as needed.

Try it like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    
    let myTextView = UITextView()
    
    var tvHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myTextView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        myTextView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        view.addSubview(myTextView)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        tvHeightConstraint = myTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            myTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            myTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            myTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
        ])
        
        myTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        myTextView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = (textView.contentSize.height > 100)
        tvHeightConstraint.isActive = textView.isScrollEnabled
    }
    
}
```

Comment: same issue. the textview takes up whole availible space when the constraint is removed, which makes delegate method enable the constraint when it's called next time. so the view keeps expanding and shrinking over and over

Comment: another issue is that the size of a textview could be more than 100, which makes it shrink when scrollview is enabled. that's why i create the constraint and init it with current frame height

Comment: Are you running the **exact** code that I posted? All by itself? Or are you using that code and trying to implement it with the rest of your layout? I don't see the issue you're describing.

Comment: i've got a different layout, so i had to adopt it. i created height constraint in storyboard, connected it through outlet, set ```myTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false``` in viewDidLoad and replaced ```textViewDidChange()``` with your implementation

Comment: @belotserkovtsev - well, I would need to see what else you're doing with your layout and see what other constraints you have that may be affecting it.

Comment: my textview is embedded in wrapper view, which is embedded in another view. none of them have width or height constraints. only space constraints. i really don't see a reson for it to not work

Comment: @belotserkovtsev - not sure what you mean by "no width or height constraints." If you've given for example, 20-pts leading and trailing "space," that defines the width. Without seeing your actual layout to understand what's going wrong, not much else I can say to help. Maybe take a look at this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965439/expanding-uitextview-inside-a-stack-view-with-scrolling-enabled ... possibly similar to what you're doing and might help.